# Using extern for structures in C

Tags: c, struct, extern

Why we cannot use `extern` to make struct accessible in more than one `.c` file?

I know that advice is to put a definition of struct in .h file and to include that `.h` file to every `.c` file we use that struct, but why we can use `extern for variables but it does not work with structs?

To `extern` variable:

1. Define variable in `.c` file
2. `extern` variable in `.c` file where we want it to be used
3. build both `.c` files, the one where variable is defined and the one where it is used

But what is the case with structures?

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: C is designed for piece-wise compilation, you can compile separate files and then piece them together. Using a structure involves code that accesses its member, how is that code supposed to be emitted if the structure definition isn't available until much later?

Comment: A variable is something with storage (at runtime). Thus, `extern` and `static` are actually hints for the linker to give two symbols with same name same storage (`extern`) or distinct storage (`static`). (This is how you may imagine it - the standard says it in different words...) However, a type (e.g. `struct`) is evaluated at compile time. It does not produce code until it is used (e.g. in a variable). Thus, storage classes (e.g. `extern` and `static`) have no effect on types. If you want to share a type, re-define it in every C file (e.g. putting it into a header which is included in every

Comment: ...C file where it shall be used.)

Comment: What would you expect it to do?  A struct is a type and has no storage of its own, so a storage class makes no sense.  Storage classes apply to variables as variables have storage,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage-class specifier `extern` is used to control linkage (see [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.2.2), i.e. which identifiers refer to the same object or function.

A `struct` however, is not a definition (i.e. storage reservation for an object or function body for a function, see 6.7.5), but a type declaration (see 6.2.5.20 and 6.7.2.1.6).

---

Remark: This distinction is also made explicit in 6.2.2.6:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to
>   be anything other than an object or a function; ...