# How to output a big structure to another module in c?

Tags: c, function

Is there a best practice for ouput function parameters of big structures that should not be changed? return pointer to struct or return whole structure?

Example:
I have a big data structure in file A that i will call from file B: (typedef struct is in header)
.h

```c
typedef struct 
{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;
    int x4;
    ...
} myStruct;
```

.c

```c
static myStruct data = {...};

errorType myfunction1(mystruct *outData)
{
    *outData = data; //copy data to output
    ...
}

errorType myfunction2(mystruct **outData)
{
    *outData = &data; //just return pointer to structure
    ...
}
```

`myfunction1` copies the whole structure, so the stack size will rise if i will call this function a lot and the processing time is rising, but the advantage is that the original data could not be changed outside of this file like with `myfunction2`.

Is there a best practice what of the both to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43829249/7508077

Comment: @EsmaeelE I dont want to use extern variables for this usage, because it should not be changed outside this file. So is it really the best option to just copy the data struct to the output parameter?

Comment: It depends on the requirements you have. If you are limited in RAM size, or if you worry about the time to copy the data, of if you fear the 2 copies of the data could diverge, you can use the pointer way. But the caller will be able to do anything, even change your data. You can use `errorType myfunction(const mystruct **outData)` to get a pointer to "read-only-data". But this can be easily casted away.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `const` keyword for the parameter in `myfunction2` so that

**Case 1**: At compilation any changes on a struct used in the caller would definitely make an `error` if the argument is also a const struct ;

**Case 2**: And at least a `warning` if the argument of the caller is not a const.

---

**Case 1:**

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

typedef struct fooStruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

}t_fooStruct;

void cpy_foo(const t_fooStruct ** structToCpy);


#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

t_fooStruct myData = {0,1,2};

void cpy_foo(const t_fooStruct ** structToCpy){
  *structToCpy = &myData;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(){

  const t_fooStruct * mainData;

  cpy_foo(&mainData);
  printf("After cpy print %d %d %d\n", mainData->a, mainData->b, mainData->c);

  mainData->a = 10;
  mainData->b = 20;
  mainData->c = 30;
  printf("After changes print %d %d %d\n\n", mainData->a, mainData->b, mainData->c);

  return 0;
}
```

At compilation this gives:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:12:15: error: assignment of member 'a' in read-only object
   12 |   mainData->a = 10;
      |               ^
main.c:13:15: error: assignment of member 'b' in read-only object
   13 |   mainData->b = 20;
      |               ^
main.c:14:15: error: assignment of member 'c' in read-only object
   14 |   mainData->c = 30;
      |
```

---

**Case 2:**

And if the structure is not a const in the main :
main.c (version without the const)

```
int main(){

  t_fooStruct * mainData;

  cpy_foo(&mainData);
[...]
```

At compilation this outputs:

```
    9 |   cpy_foo(&mainData);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           t_fooStruct ** {aka struct fooStruct **}
In file included from main.c:3:
foo.h:12:35: note: expected 'const t_fooStruct **' {aka 'const struct fooStruct **'} but argument is of type 't_fooStruct **' {aka 'struct fooStruct **'}
   12 | void cpy_foo(const t_fooStruct ** structToCpy);
```